# What was the command relationship between Captain Sisko and General Martok in DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon, star-trek-dominion

In the Season 5, Episode 26 (''Call to Arms''), we see Captain Sisko communicating with General Martok in these kinds of tone:

> General Martok, take a defensive position near the Defiant. They have to finish deploying those mines no matter the cost.

and

> Sisko: General, take your ship and patrol the border. At the first
> sight of the Dominion ships-
>
> Martok: I will sound the alarm.
>
> Sisko: Don't engage the enemy. Get back to the station as soon as you can.
> We're going to need you here.

These sound like direct orders or commands. Captain Sisko didn't even say stuff like "please", "we recommend", or "if you'd be so kind". If their ranks are anything like today's armies and navies, General Martok outranks Captain Sisko. I don't think it is appropriate to order around a higher-ranking allied officer like that. What is the command relationship between Sisko and Martok, and why does it appear that Martok takes order from Sisko?

Answer (score 13):

General Martok is the commanding officer of the Klingon detachment to DS9 which is there to support DS9 against the Dominion and is therefore subordinate to DS9. [(1)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Martok#The_Dominion_War)

This leeds to Sisko as commanding officer of DS9 able to give orders to General Martok / the Klingon detachment even if he has a lower rank.